# vue composition API - computed property inside ref variable

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

I have the following code:

```
    <template>
      <div class="row flex justify-center w-full h-full" style="min-height: 320px;>
       <q-select style="min-width: 92px;" class="w-full" outlined :options="options" label="Número de parcelas" emit-value map-options v-model="installments"></q-select>
      </div>
  </template>

    <script>
    import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
    import { useStore } from 'vuex'
    import { defineComponent, ref, computed } from 'vue'
    
    export default defineComponent({
      name: 'PageIndex',
      components: {
        loading
      },
    
      setup () {
        const store = useStore()
        const $q = useQuasar()
        let installments = ref(12)
        const product = computed(() => {
          return store.getters['checkout/getCheckoutProduct']
        })
        let options = ref([
          {
            label: `12x de R$ ${(product.value.price / 12)}`,
            value: 12
          },
          {
            label: `11x de R$ ${(product.value.price / 11)}`,
            value: 11
          }
        ])
        return {
          product,
          options,
          installments
          }
      }
    })
    </script>
```

The problem is that  is returning UNDEFINED, even product.value.price correctly showing inside VUE devtools inside my vuex. Also, other places on component are getting the product value, but... the 'options' do not work.

Note that options have the variable inside it, how can i pass a variable from computed to the ref() variable ?!

Comment: Why variable "options" is not computed as well? It is calculated from reactive property - product.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to use it as a computed property as well ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref will be invoked only one time. It is used in setup, so it works like onCreated hook. You should have used computed property. It calculates reactive content.

Check my demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vuex-4-vue-router-forked-4u0lj?file=/src/views/Home.vue

Comment: Using computed property on options really worked to resolve. I was used to old vue2 way.